# Set unique infoWindow content on click for each of several unique markers using Google Maps

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've built a bus-tracking application using Ruby on Rails that displays a user's location as well as the location of several nearby buses all on one map. Each bus has its own marker with an event listener that opens an info window on click.

I want each info window to display a unique descriptor based on paramaters of the bus it's attached to. I'm creating each marker using a loop through every element in the array of buses, `displayBuses`, and assigning the corresponding element in the array of descriptors, `busInfo`.

I've found a few articles here on Stack Overflow that model what I'm trying to do, some by creating multiple `infoWindows` and some by creating one `infoWindow` and using Google Maps' `setContent` function to update the descriptor.

When I started out, I was trying to create a new marker, descriptor, and info window for each bus, but I wasn't getting any info windows. Next I tried to create one window and use `setContent` to update it each time, but I had `busInfo` as a string that updated each time; I was getting content in the info windows, but it was the same for each bus. I changed `busInfos` to an array to store a different string for each bus. Now
my code is creating the info windows properly, but it's not displaying the descriptors (each window pops up empty).

Here is the relevant code:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

var busLatLng, busMarker, i;

var busInfos = [];

for (i = 0; i < displayBuses.length; i++) {  
    var busLat = displayBuses[i].LATITUDE;
    var busLng = displayBuses[i].LONGITUDE;
    var busNum = displayBuses[i].VEHICLE;
    var busRoute = displayBuses[i].ROUTE;
    var busStop = displayBuses[i].TIMEPOINT;

    busLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(busLat, busLng);

    busMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: busLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Bus number ' + busNum,
        icon: busIcon,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
    });

    busInfos[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'Bus number ' + busNum + ' is on Route ' + busRoute + '. The next stop is at ' + busStop + '.'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(busMarker, 'click', (function(busMarker) {
         return function() {
             infoWindow.setContent(busInfo[i]);
             infoWindow.open(map, busMarker);
         }
    })(busMarker));
}
```

And here's the complete locations.js.erb file:

```js
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function() {
 var currentLat = gon.current_lat;
 var currentLng = gon.current_lng;
 var displayBuses = gon.display_buses;

 var currentLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(currentLat, currentLng);

 function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   center: currentLatLng,
   zoom: 15,
   scrollwheel: false
  });

  setMarkers(map);
 }

 function setMarkers(map) {
  var userMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: currentLatLng,
   map: map,
   title: 'User',
   animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
  });

  var userInfo = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: 'You are here.'
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(userMarker, 'click', function() {
   userInfo.open(map, userMarker);
  });

  var imgHt = 30;
  var imgWd = imgHt*1.5;

  var busIcon = {
     url: "<%= asset_path 'bus-marker.png' %>",
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(imgHt, imgWd),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(imgWd/2, imgHt)
    };

  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  var busLatLng, busMarker, i;

  var busInfos = [];

  for (i = 0; i < displayBuses.length; i++) {  
     var busLat = displayBuses[i].LATITUDE;
   var busLng = displayBuses[i].LONGITUDE;
   var busNum = displayBuses[i].VEHICLE;
   var busRoute = displayBuses[i].ROUTE;
   var busStop = displayBuses[i].TIMEPOINT;

     busLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(busLat, busLng);

     busMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: busLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Bus number ' + busNum,
    icon: busIcon,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
     });

     busInfos[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Bus number ' + busNum + ' is on Route ' + busRoute + '. The next stop is at ' + busStop + '.'
   });

     google.maps.event.addListener(busMarker, 'click', (function(busMarker) {
          return function() {
              infoWindow.setContent(busInfo[i]);
              infoWindow.open(map, busMarker);
          }
     })(busMarker));
  }
 };

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
});
```

I'm using the gem `gon` to pull ruby variables in from the controller, but after tinkering with the JS console I feel confident that those are coming in correctly. I just can't figure out why changing `busInfos` to an array is causing it not to display properly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Noticed how you passed `busMarker` to create the callback function, pass `busInfo[i]` as well.

Comment: that makes sense to me, but now I'm getting an error message:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

guessing this is a simple syntax error, but at wit's end...

Comment: I hope you didn't use `busInfo[i]` as the parameter name

Comment: yeah, one would hope right?

Answer (score 0):

@Musa, you are correct that I need to pass `busInfo[i]` as well. It took me a minute to figure out which function was sending the arguments and which was receiving them, but now I have it set up as follows:

```js
busInfo[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: 'Bus number ' + busNum + ' is on Route ' + busRoute + '. The next stop is at ' + busStop + '.'
});

google.maps.event.addListener(busMarker, 'click', (function(busMarker, busInfo) {
  return function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(busInfo.content);
    infoWindow.open(map, busMarker);
  }
})(busMarker, busInfo[i]));
```

The other issue was that I was using `.setContent` to add the object `busInfo` into the window instead of its string attribute `.content`. Now the windows are displaying correctly.

Thanks for your help!